# implement a semaphore

Tags: semaphore, glib

It appears that glib provides mutexes and conditions as thread synchronization primitives, but what about generic [semaphores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) (in the sense that they support the original P and V operations?)  Am I correct in understanding a `GCond` as equivalent to a binary semaphore, with `g_cond_signal` being equivalent to `P`, and `g_cond_wait` being equivalent to `V`?  But what about semaphores not restricted to a maximum value of 1?

I thought of something like this:

```
struct semaphore {
  int n;
  GMutex sem_lock;
  GCond sem_cond;
}
```

Where the `P` operation would now look something like this:

```
void semaphore_P (struct semaphore *sem)
{
   g_mutex_lock(sem->sem_lock);
   while (sem->n == 0)
     g_cond_wait(sem->sem_cond, sem->sem_lock);
   --sem->n;
   g_mutex_unlock(sem->sem_lock);
}
```

Is there a simpler way to get at the functionality of pthreads' `sem_wait` and `sem_post` from within glib?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An [asynchronous queue](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Asynchronous-Queues.html) can be used as a semaphore:

- initialization: GAsyncQueue *queue = g_async_queue_new();
- the V operation: g_async_queue_push(queue, GINT_TO_POINTER(1));
- the P operation: g_async_queue_pop(queue);

The size of the queue serves as the counter of the semaphore.
The second parameter to g_async_queue_push may be any pointer except for NULL.
However, if you want to use the semaphore for some consumer/producer task, then sending in a pointer to some data will be useful.

In some cases, [a thread pool](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Thread-Pools.html) may fit even better.